# Magento 2 REST API: extension attribute for saleability not working for some products

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, plugin, stock-status

I needed product's stock status in the product listing API:

> V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=144

So I made a plugin as follows:

```
<?php

            namespace Vendor\StockInfoAPI\Plugin;

            use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;

            class ProductGet{
            protected $productExtensionFactory;
            protected $productFactory;

            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory $productExtensionFactory,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
                \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface $mediaGallery,
                \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
            )
            {
                $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
                $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
                $this->logger = $logger;
                $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
                $this->productExtensionFactory = $productExtensionFactory;
                $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
                $this->mediaGallery = $mediaGallery;
            }

            public function afterGet(
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product){

                $product = $this->getExtensionAttributesItem($product);
                return $product;
            }


            protected function getExtensionAttributesItem(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
            {
                $imageUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                if($product->getImage()){
                    $product->setCustomAttribute("image", $product->getImage());
                }
                if (!$product->isSaleable()){
                    $qty = "Out of Stock";
                }
                else{
                    $qty = "In-Stock";
                }
                $extensionattributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();

                $extensionattributes->setQty($qty);
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product->getSku());
                $productPriceBySku = $productCollection->getPrice();
                $extensionattributes->setPrice($productPriceBySku);
                $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionattributes);

                return $product;


            }

            /**
             * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject
             * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $products
             * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
             */
                public function afterGetList(
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
                $products
                )
                {
                    foreach ($products->getItems() as $product) {
                        $this->afterGet($subject, $product);
                    }
                    return $products;
                }
            }
```

As you can see, I am essentially using the same function for fetching the details in product listing API and the product detail API:

> V1/products/:SKU

Now the problem is: for some products, I am getting wrong stock status in the listing API.

In the product detail it is working fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
foreach ($products->getItems() as $product) {
     $this->getExtensionAttributesItem($product);
}
return $products;
```

Not sure it'll work or not.

Comment: this doesn't work